# heroku connection refused at precompile with initialize_on_precompile = true

Tags: heroku, deployment, assets, heroku-postgres

I got this error

*could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?*

At precompilation, I know that one of the workaround is to put initialize_on_precompile to false **but I do need my application to be initialized** for my css to work.

This is the full error:
could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_3eatwoqg4vdl/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable this with an *experimental* lab feature, [user-env-compile:](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile)

> This Heroku Labs feature adds experimental support for having an app’s
>   config vars be present in the environment during slug compilation.

**Note:**

> The features added through labs are experimental and may change or be
>   removed without notice.